# Set sudo umask apart from the user calling it

Tags: debian, permissions, security, sudo, umask

**The problem:** I set my `umask` for my user to be 0077. Now I use `sudo` instead of `su` when I need super-user access, and the problem is that whenever I execute a software installation using `sudo` with something like `sudo pip3 install sympy`, all the software installed by that gets the permission masked by 0077, meaning all these libs are not reachable by any user!!

**The question:** How can get all sudo calls to have the mask 0022 while my user calls have a mask of 0022?

**Note:** I did add the line `Defaults umask = 0022` in `sudo visudo` and still didn't work. Is this everything to be done?

**How do I set my `umask`**: I have the line `umask 0077` added to `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to have been overlooked:

```
Defaults umask_override
```

which does what was asked (see the [sudoers manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers)):

> **`umask_override`**
>   If set, `sudo` will set the `umask` as specified by `sudoers` without modification. This makes it possible to specify a ***more permissive*** `umask` in sudoers than the user's own `umask` and matches historical behavior. If `umask_override` is not set, `sudo` will set the umask to be the union of the user's umask and what is specified in `sudoers`. This flag is off by default. If set, `sudo` will run the command in a pseudo-pty even if no I/O logging is being gone. A malicious program run under `sudo` could conceivably fork a background process that retains to the user's terminal device after the main program has finished executing. Use of this option will make that impossible. This flag is off by default.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to test it though :)

Comment: Be careful editing /etc/sudoers using sudo. Syntax errors result may result in a lockout.

Comment: That's what `visudo` is for.